# Get public feeds of a Facebook Page in Node.js

Tags: facebook, node.js, facebook-graph-api, module

I'm developing a simple node/express/jade website that fetch all the public feeds of a Facebook Page.

I create an application from wich i get client_id (APP_ID) and client_secret (APP_SECRET).

My code works, and it's okay but i wonder if this is the correct way of handling this need.

Here is the code:

```
var https = require('https'),
    concat = require('concat-stream'),
    async = require('async');

function FacebookPage(pageId) {
    if (!(this instanceof FacebookPage))
        return new FacebookPage(pageId);

    this.pageId = pageId;
}

FacebookPage.prototype.getPublicFeeds = function (callback) {

var pageId = this.pageId;

async.waterfall([

  function (done) {
        var params = {
            hostname: 'graph.facebook.com',
            port: 443,
            path: '/oauth/access_token?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&' +
                'client_secret=MY_CLIENT_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials',
            method: 'GET'
        };

        https.get(params, function (response) {
            //response is a stream so it is an EventEmitter
            response.setEncoding("utf8");

            //More compact
            response.pipe(concat(function (data) {
                done(null, data);
            }));

            response.on("error", done);
        });
  },

  function (access_token, done) {

        var params = {
            hostname: 'graph.facebook.com',
            port: 443,
            path: '/v2.0/' + pageId + '/feed?' + access_token,
            method: 'GET'
        };

        https.get(params, function (response) {
            //response is a stream so it is an EventEmitter
            response.setEncoding("utf8");

            //More compact
            response.pipe(concat(function (data) {
                callback(null, JSON.parse(data));
            }));

            response.on("error", callback);
        });

  }]);
};

module.exports = FacebookPage;
```

EDIT: thank to @Tobi I can delete the part of getting the access_token by putting access_token=app_id|app_secret as explained here:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why you'd want to include to OAuth stuff (which I think can't work because you don't exchange the `code` for an actual access token if I understand this correctly)...

According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/page/feed/ you need `an access token ... to view publicly shared posts.`, this means you can also use an app access token in the form of `app_id|app_secret`.

You can then use the

```
GET /{page_id}/feed
```

endpoint by passing the `access_token` paramenter with your app access token. I'd also recommend to use the NPM modules `request` or `restler`, these make the HTTP handling much easier.

Comment: I read the Access Tokens documentation page but I focused on Page Access Token not seeing what you were suggesting.

So I think you are right and I'll add the documentation to the OP.

I keep this question open a little more just to see if someone else would comment.

Thank you very much

Comment: this is correct, you only need an app access token to get the feed of a facebook app. you only need to a page access token for posting as a page, or for getting access to non-public stuff like insights.